# WP7 & WP8 compatibility

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I can't find a straight answer for compatibility issues between WP7 and new WP8.

For example: what if some popular apps like facebook, twitter will be updated to WP8? Will they still work on WP7 (7.8)? Or the latest WP7-compatible version will stay in Marketplace for WP7 users and new fo WP8 will be just for WP8 users?

I'm asking because many of my friends are interested in buying Lumia 800 in great price, but they worried about limited number of apps in future.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The latest WP7-compatible version will stay in Marketplace for WP7 users
```

Exactly. And developers can continue to update the WP7 version of an app even when a WP8 version has been published.

Answer (score 0):

If an application is compiled for Windows Phone 8, it will NOT work on Windows Phone 7.x.

Comment: Dzięki! I know that but my question is more about "is Microsoft going to kill all existing WP7 apps or will leave last WP7 version together with new one for WP8?"

Comment: I do not think that Microsoft is going to "kill all existing WP7 apps", there are millions of WP7 mobiles out there, and this is not going to change for a while. These mobiles can only run these applications.

Comment: Besides it is up to developer / producer to estimate what windows mobile market(s) they want to target. I would target WP7 app if I did not need to use anything that is unique to WP8. Otherwise, try two create to versions of the app, one for WP8 and one ("stripped down") for WP7.

Comment: I have the same opinion on that, but just wanted to be sure. So its going to be plenty of apps like "NameOfapp for WP7" and "NameOfApp for WP8"? I guess MS will not like it...